# Running Python script over multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, linux, opensuse

I use python in opensuse, my problem is i need to execute large data in my folder.
for example

```
python myprogram.py 20140101.txt
```

i still need to run for a lot data with like that naming (20140101.txt) ex 20140204 etc..
my question is how to make my program running automatically for all data together.

Comment: hi everyone thanks for the attention. my code working now.
the correct anwser is

for file in data/*.txt do python myprogram.py $file; done

thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

use bash like this:

```
for file in /dir/*.txt
do
    python myprogram.py $file     
done
```

Comment: chers...i try your advise, but im not clear why just only my last data can be executed.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure python solution, have a look at [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html).

It is part of the python standard library and let's you loop over files given via standard input or via a list of files, e.g.:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

So you could do:

```
./python myprogram 2014*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The glob module is useful for processing multiple files with different names.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: thanks i will find some tutorial for this

Answer (score 0):

A python solution would be to use "glob". It helps you creating lists of files' name based on a certain pattern. You can then loop through those filenames to execute your commands on. See example below.

```
import glob

txt_files = glob.glob("201401*.txt")

for txt in txt_files:
    print txt
    my_txt_file = open(txt, "r")
```

For further reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.htm

Comment: ah this is new for me, ill try it